# Scheduler in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have the following `function.json` for my Azure Function which triggers at the particular time as set.

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "* 30 10 * * *"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to schedule **another** trigger with different time, but for the same Azure Function. Is it possible to add multiple triggering time for same function? If not, then please suggest an alternative way to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add more than one trigger to a function. However, you can solve it by putting the relevant code in a helper method, and then have two different functions call out to the helper. It's a small additional pain, but it will avoid duplicating any key logic.

Comment: Thanks,
It worked as charm.
However, i was able to create another slightly different flow.
I removed the very entry for which the function is triggered, from the list. Then I fetched the last entry from the list and updated the trigger of the function.json of the Azure Function, from within itself. So, on the execution of the function, it will configure itself for the next execution.